# How do I specify scope in build.sbt

Tags: sbt

I have a variable libDir defined in Global & when I try to use it inside one of the sub-projects (with specifying the scope), it fails with:

[info] Loading project definition from /Users/chichu/ws/tip/TestMain/project
References to undefined settings:

*/*:libDir from Streaming/*:install (/Users/chinchu/ws/tip/TestMain/build.sbt:124)
     Did you mean TestRoot/*:libDir ?

Here's the snippet from build.sbt:

===

def Streaming(name: String, dir: String,
              archiveName: String, main: String): Project = {
  ...
  ...

```
install := {
  val jarName = assembly.value
  sbt.IO.copyFile(jarName, (libDir in Global).value) // copy over the jar
}
```

}

..
..

lazy val installDir =  SettingKeyFile

libDir := baseDirectory.value / "install/lib"

==

Why is it not able to resolve "libDir" even when I specify "in Global" ? I also tried "libDir in TestRoot" & it reports "error: not found: value TestRoot"

Thanks
-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification [says](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html#referring-to-scopes-in-a-build-definition), that if you define a setting like this:

```
libDir := baseDirectory.value / "install/lib"
```

It will set a task and a configuration scope to `Global`, but a project scope will be set to current project (that is a root project in your case).

When you refer to your setting as `libDir in Global`, you set configuration scope to `Global` but still, you are in the current build, that is some project, that tries to define the `install` setting.

You should define your `libDir` like this:

```
libDir in Global := baseDirectory.value / "install/lib"
```

which will set also the project scope to `Global`.

#### Example build.sbt

```
lazy val installDir = settingKey[File]("ff")

lazy val install = taskKey[Unit]("prints install")

installDir in Global := baseDirectory.value / "install/lib"

val projectA = project.in(file("projectA")).settings(
  install := {
    val install = (installDir in Global).value
    println(install)
  }
)

val projectB = project
```

### Alternative Solution

Alternatively you could give a root project an explicit id, that is in your main `build.sbt` add a line

```
val root = Project("root", file("."))
```

then in your `install` task refer to `Global` in that project (`root` is a name of the project)

```
(libDir in Global in root).value
```

#### Example build.sbt

```
lazy val installDir = settingKey[File]("ff")

lazy val install = taskKey[Unit]("prints install")

installDir := baseDirectory.value / "install/lib"

lazy val root = Project("root", file("."))

lazy val projectA = project.in(file("projectA")).settings(
  install := {
    val install = (installDir in Global in root).value
    println(install)
  }
)

lazy val projectB = project
```